# How to select section from a configuration file

Tags: regex, awk

I have a configuration file like this

```
interface xy
  disable
blabla
object name object-1
  param1 host 192.168.23.45
  param2 host 10.20.30.40
this is not an object
this is not an object    
object name object-2
  param1 network 10.200.192.23 255.255.255.0
  param2 network 10.1.39.0 255.255.192.0
   param3 range 172.34.12.45 172.34.12.47
this is not an object
  is not an object param
```

I need to select all od the sections begin with object followed with one or more lines indented by a space or several spaces. The expected output should be this one:

```
object name object-1
  param1 host 192.168.23.45
  param2 host 10.20.30.40
object name object-2
  param1 network 10.200.192.23 255.255.255.0
  param2 network 10.1.39.0 255.255.192.0
   param3 range 172.34.12.45 172.34.12.47
```

I wrote this regex `/^object.*\n(^\s.*\n)+/mg` and it works fine when I validate it at  https://regex101.com/ but it doesn't work when I try `awk '/^object.*\n(^\s.*\n)+/m' file.cfg` nor this one example `awk '/^object/,/^(\s.*\n)/' file.cfg`. Can somebody explain me what is wrong?

Comment: With GNU sed: `sed 's/^[^ ]/\n&/g' file.cfg | sed -n '/^object/,/^$/{/^$/d;p}'`

Comment: I cant imagine why this question has multiple downvotes since it has sample input, expected output, and the OPs attempt to solve the problem themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using GNU awk for `\S` shorthand for `[[:space:]]`:

```
$ awk '/^\S/{f=/^object/} f' file
object name object-1
  param1 host 192.168.23.45
  param2 host 10.20.30.40
object name object-2
  param1 network 10.200.192.23 255.255.255.0
  param2 network 10.1.39.0 255.255.192.0
   param3 range 172.34.12.45 172.34.12.47
```

or with any awk:

```
awk '/^[^ \t]/{f=/^object/} f' file
```

Testing a regexp in regex101.com or any other web site proves that that regexp works in that web site, nothing else. In particular it doesn't mean it'll work in any command-line tool (e.g. awk, sed, or grep) as every tool uses different regexp varieties (e.g. BRE, ERE, or PCRE) with different extensions, different options, different delimiters, etc.

Your regexps were failing as they're using non-standard extensions (`\s` and whatever `/m` is supposed to mean) and assuming the whole of the input is in memory when in fact awk reads 1 line at a time by default, and are anchored to the start of the input (by `^`) when you want them to match mid-input.

There is no BRE or ERE that would ONLY match what you're trying to match. Maybe you could figure out a PCRE to do it but trying to solve your problem with just a regexp is far too complicated for the simple thing you're trying to do vs writing a tiny script to do it as shown above.

[Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/).

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the input file to include 2x consecutive `object` blocks and a `object`-EOF block

```
$ cat file.cfg
interface xy
  disable
blabla
object name object-1
  param1 host 192.168.23.45
  param2 host 10.20.30.40
object name object-2
  param1 network 10.200.192.23 255.255.255.0
  param2 network 10.1.39.0 255.255.192.0
   param3 range 172.34.12.45 172.34.12.47
this is not an object
this is not an object
this is not an object
  is not an object param
object name object-2
  param1 network 10.200.192.23 255.255.255.0
  param2 network 10.1.39.0 255.255.192.0
```

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
/^object/                        { printme=1 }
/^[[:alnum:]]/ && $1 != "object" { printme=0 }
printme
' file.cfg
```

This generates:

```
object name object-1
  param1 host 192.168.23.45
  param2 host 10.20.30.40
object name object-2
  param1 network 10.200.192.23 255.255.255.0
  param2 network 10.1.39.0 255.255.192.0
   param3 range 172.34.12.45 172.34.12.47
object name object-2
  param1 network 10.200.192.23 255.255.255.0
  param2 network 10.1.39.0 255.255.192.0
```

**NOTE:** Cyrus' `sed` comment/answer also generates this output for the modified input file.

Comment: I've made some experiment and there is one thing I can't understand. When I run `awk /^object/'` it selects just the rows with the word `object` at the beginning. But when I run `awk /^object { printme=1} printme'` it selects also the sub-lines. Why?

Comment: @samuG the 2nd piece of `awk` code in your comment is invalid so not sure what the actually issue is; if you're unable to figure out what's going on I'd suggest opening a new question, making sure to post sample input, desired output, the `awk` command you're running and the (wrong) output generated by said code

Comment: @EdMorton thanks for the literature. I've used another sources to learn something about awk, but this one looks more complex. And also thanks for the answer.

Comment: @markp-fuso you're true. I made a typo at the formatting. The correct form is `awk /^object/'` and `awk '/^object/ {printme=1} printme'`. Sorry for that.